# How can I show both the val and threshold on the y-axis at the same time in Log Analytics?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a line graph and I'd like to include a threshold as well on the Y-axis. Log Analytics is asking me to choose one or the other but I'd like both. How can I do that?

[image: log analytics image]

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use below query to accomplish your requirement.

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Name == "UtilizationPercentage" and TimeGenerated > ago(15m)
| extend Threshold=95
| summarize Val = any(Val), Threshold = any(Threshold) by TimeGenerated
```